# QGIS TimeManager with multiple features at one time?

Tags: qgis, layers, csv, timeslider, timemanager

Since the data I have to deal with is really large, it is not practical to separate every feature into one line in the CSV file.

Is there any way to animate them as a whole layer?

I have approximately 26000 features in one layer for each time interval, and 300 time intervals that i need to implement the animation.

**EDIT:**

I want to display links and animate their colour changes based on the magnitudes.

Basically, all links should show up at all time, but since their magnitudes change with time, and I colour coded the style, the colour of the links will change as time passes.

My previous data format is: magnitude; time; coordinates in WKT format. one example is: 4; 2015-01-01; (642044 4862161, 642319 4862144). However, in this form, if I need to include all the data, it requires 7,000,000 lines which exceeds the maximum row limit for excel. So now I want to know if there is any chances to animate them as a whole layer, or some ways to solve this problem.

Also if I input all the data, the program probably becomes really slow.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Please add more details about the current format of your data. Currently we can only guess what you are trying to work with.

Comment: My data format is: magnitude; time; coordinates in WKT format.

Answer (score 1):

When the row limit of Excel is exceeded, this should be an indication to switch to a database. Use PostGIS, put an index on the timestamp and animating that table with QGIS Time Manager will be a breeze.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for establishing a database? especially the indexing. thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, google PostGIS + your operating system